# How to find the total lines of csv files in a directory on Linux?

Tags: linux, csv, find, rowcount, wc

Working with huge CSV files for data analytics, we commonly need to know the row count of all csv files located in a particular folder.

But how to do it with just only one command in Linux?

Answer (score 10):

If you want to check the total line of all the .csv files in a directory, you can use ***find*** and ***wc***:

```
 find . -type f -name '*.csv' -exec wc -l {} +
```

Comment: Probably just marginal, but keep in mind `getconf ARG_MAX`

Answer (score 5):

To get lines count for every file recursively you can use Cesar's answer:

```
$ LANG=C find /tmp/test -type f -name '*.csv' -exec wc -l '{}' +
 49 /tmp/test/sub/3.csv
 22 /tmp/test/1.csv
419 /tmp/test/2.csv
490 total
```

To get total lines count for all files recursive:

```
$ LANG=C find /tmp/test -type f -name '*.csv' -exec cat '{}' + | wc -l
490
```